# Use python requests to write a curl command with parameters like -u and -T

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to replicate a curl command of the following format:

```
curl -X PUT -w "<some string>" \
     -u <user_name>:<password> \
     -T <some_string> \
     <some_url>
```

I've tried to add the parameters in headers in the following format, but it didn't work:

```
url = ''
headers = {'u': '<user>', 'T': '<string>'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Why not using pycurl a Python wrapper for `libcurl`. See http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html

Comment: Google "curl to python", enter the first result and add your curl. You will get the correct python code.

Comment: did you tried this https://curl.trillworks.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `-u` and `-T` flags aren't headers, they trigger specific behaviour in curl. You need to [understand that behaviour](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and look up how to do the equivalent thing in [the requests manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

[`-X`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-X) sets the request method, here `PUT`, which corresponds to [`requests.put`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request),
[`-u`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) corresponds to the [`auth=(user, pass)` argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication),
[`-T`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T) uploads a file, which corresponds to the [`files={...}` parameter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Putting it all together, you want something like:

```
requests.put(url, 
             auth=('username', 'password'),
             files={'file': open('filename', 'rb')})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you use curl with put,but you use requests with post.
2. please read  requests'doc .

3.response = requests.put('http://aaaa', auth=('', ''),data={},files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')})