# How to convert a cURL request to Python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a cURL request that is working fine.

```
curl http://localhost:5000/models/images/generic/infer.json -XPOST -F job_id='123' -F dont_resize='dont_resize' -F snapshot_epoch='100' -F image_file='@/home/hellouser/Downloads/infer/Users/User01/Images/tiles/999/00.jpg'`
```

I have a python script where I want to execute the same request. But I get the following error,

> {
>   "error": {
>   "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iteritems'",
>   "type": "AttributeError"
>   }
>   }

Here is the python code,

```
import requests
data = {
    'job_id': '123',
    'dont_resize': 'dont_resize',
    'snapshot_epoch': '100',
    'image_file': '@/home/hellouser/Downloads/infer/Users/User01/Images/tiles/999/00.jpg'    }

url = 'http://localhost:5000/models/images/generic/infer.json'
r = requests.post(url=url, data=data)
```

Any idea how to properly convert the code? Should I pass `file=file` in request?

Comment: Paste the minimal working code

Comment: You might find this site useful: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @fordy thanks, I already tried it. The output from there (trillworks) was still giving errors when I sent it from Python.

Comment: @Melon what seems to be missing from the code? I'll check if it needs to be added.

Comment: it looks like the path in your backend is complaining about something, so you'll need to post the piece of code that deals with `iteritems` also seems like you are working with `python 2.x` you might want to label it as such

Comment: That's the problem...I don't (and can't) have access to the backend code. I've been doing hit and trials all day to no avail.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54143121/476 for starters…

Comment: @Mujeeb Imports are missing for example

Comment: Added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {
    'job_id': '123',
    'dont_resize': 'dont_resize',
    'snapshot_epoch': '100',
}
files = {
    'image_file': open('/home/hellouser/Downloads/infer/Users/User01/Images/tiles/999/00.jpg', 'rb')
}

url = 'http://localhost:5000/models/images/generic/infer.json'
r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, files=files)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this but it didn't work earlier (don't remember the error). But much code has changed after that, I'll give it another try and let you know (later).

Comment: Ok @Mujeeb, just remember, the param name is `files`

Comment: Shouldn't the file be opened with just `r`, instead of `rb` for Python 3?

Comment: use rb for binary

Comment: Thanks. Found a detailed answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644285